# How to create a multi label text classification model for small dataset in production

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

I have a multi-label text classification dataset which is very small around 80Kb, I am only going to receive a small amount of data for training from my client. But it is expected to build a high accuracy model for classifying each utterance into multiple targets based on the utterance. How should i prepare the dataset, which models would be best and how shall I aim for the highest accuracy

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pre-trained model like Bert for feature extraction. Then use these features to train your own classifier using the data received.

Comment: thanks for the advice!